# Why is this JSON schema valid?

Tags: json, jsonschema

The following schema and document validate just fine even though the last line of the document uses "none" as a value which is not in the enum.

```
{
        "$schema"     : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title"       : "Test schema",

        "definitions" : {
                "xxx_type" : {
                        "enum" : [ "X1", "X2", "X3" ]
                },

                "xxx_info" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                                "date" : { "type" : "string" },
                                "category" : {
                                        "type" : "array",
                                        "items" : { "$ref" : "#/definitions/xxx_type" }
                                }
                        },
                        "required" : [ "date", "category" ]
                }
        },

        "XXX" : {
                "type" : "array",
                "items" : {
                        "$ref" : "#/definitions/xxx_info"
                }
        }
}

{
        "XXX" : [ { "date" : "2015/01/01", "category" : [ "X1" ] },
                  { "date" : "2015/02/01", "category" : [ "X2" ] },
                  { "date" : "2015/03/01", "category" : [ "X3" ] }
                  { "date" : "2015/04/01", "category" : [ "none" ] }
        ]
}
```

The following says invalid.  (The two lines before the "XXX" definition are the only real difference.)  Here the "none" is invalid.

```
{
        "$schema"     : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title"       : "Test schema",

        "definitions" : {
                "xxx_type" : {
                        "enum" : [ "X1", "X2", "X3" ]
                },

                "xxx_info" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                                "date" : { "type" : "string" },
                                "category" : {
                                        "type" : "array",
                                        "items" : { "$ref" : "#/definitions/xxx_type" }
                                }
                        },
                        "required" : [ "date", "category" ]
                }
        },

        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
                "XXX" : {
                        "type" : "array",
                        "items" : {
                                "$ref" : "#/definitions/xxx_info"
                        }
                }
        }
}

{
        "XXX" : [ { "date" : "2015/01/01", "category" : [ "X1" ] },
                  { "date" : "2015/02/01", "category" : [ "X2" ] },
                  { "date" : "2015/03/01", "category" : [ "X3" ] }
                  { "date" : "2015/04/01", "category" : [ "none" ] }
        ]
}
```

Comment: In the first one, you don't seem to have used the `properties` keyword - you need to put your `"XXX"` inside `properties`, otherwise it's just ignored as an unfamiliar keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one says it is valid because it does not validate the xxx property.
But on the second one you have changed the jsonSchema to meet the JSON document and this time it is validating the xxx property using the jsonSchema and the property is invalid because it contains an invalid node the one with the category "none"

Comment: Are you saying that without the property definition, the document will be valid as long as it is syntactically valid (not semantically valid)?

Comment: Yes. In the first example, because you don't set the type and the properties The JSON graph does not contain anything that breaks the rules stated in the JSON-schema. 

In the second one, the JSON schema says that the json must be an object with a property xxx that must be an array and each element of the array, if any, has to conform to XXX_info.